# Calculate catchment area with pgrouting

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I have the road networks from osm and I created topology.

I know that dijkstra algorithm works, because I calculated the shortest path from two point layers.
Now I would like to calculate catchment area for my points (from first layer).

I checked, how works pgr_drivingDistance. The result is far from expected.

I tried these codes:

```
SELECT pgr_drivingDistance( 'select id, source, target, leng as cost from osm_roads'
, 221, 1000)
     FROM osm_roads_vertices_pgr
```

where 221 is number of nodes. This code executed for a very long time and I had to stop it.

```
CREATE TABLE distances AS (SELECT a.node AS id, a.agg_cost AS distance, b.the_geom
FROM pgr_drivingDistance(
    'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, leng as cost FROM public.osm_roads',
    221,
    1000
) a, osm_roads_vertices_pgr b WHERE a.node = b.id);
```

but in this case result had only one point (start point) and this is not true.

I attach two screenshots:

The first, result from PgAdmin.

[image]

The second from visualization in QGIS.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Do you have an idea, how can I iprove my code?

I'm using PostgreSQL 10 with PostGIS 2.5.2 and Pgrouting 2.6.2.

Comment: your first query executes `pgr_drivingDistance` once **for every row** in `osm_roads_vertices_pgr`; it simply fetches the full table, but instead of selecting columns that function will be executed for each row. just omit the `FROM osm_roads_vertices_pgr`. as to your actual issue; without knowing your network, this is impossible to debug (it might just as well be the expected result, and it just needs an explanation as to why it is)

Comment: I have just added two screenshots.

Comment: what's the unit of `leng`, meter? What happens if you replace it with `ST_Length(geom::GEOGRAPHY) AS cost`?

Comment: I have this message: "Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography."
When I delete ":GEOGRAPHY", result is the same.
Unit of leng is meter. 
Coordinates are also in meters (EPSG:2180).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

My roads network wasn't good splitted. Node 220 had not connection.

I had to use pgr_nodeNetwork.