# Extract all dangles of a service area in QGIS

Tags: qgis, service-area, dangle, endpoints

I use the `Service area (from layer)` tool in QGIS (3.34), which allows to output the boundary nodes. I was expecting that this tool only returns the nodes at all dangles of the calculated service area lines, but I get the dangles *plus* all other vertices of the service area (as one multipoint geometry). This seems like a bug to me—or I have the wrong understanding of "boundary nodes".

What is the most performant way to only get the service area dangles as nodes?

### What I have tried so far

---

**[Tara's solution here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/428926/52808) (version 1)**

Result with visible errors:

[image: Tara's solution with errors]

[Based on this model](https://nextcloud.stadtkreation.de/index.php/s/cLgk3Pge6H94GEy)

---

**[BERA's solution here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/427793/52808) (version 2)**

Same result with errors.

[Based on this model](https://nextcloud.stadtkreation.de/index.php/s/kzqrkniHdbizKMo)

---

**[Babel's solution here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/427802/52808) (version 3)**

All service area vertices remain. Obviously I am still missing something.

[Based on this model](https://nextcloud.stadtkreation.de/index.php/s/kfpsciEDfRssC7R)

---

[You can find the complete test data here](https://nextcloud.stadtkreation.de/index.php/s/iccFoaRdgSbLTTW)

Comment: You want to find all end points of the service area(s)?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm looking for. Should I better use the term "end points", as "dangles" might be misleading?

Comment: Alternatives to finding dangles: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/427802/88814 
and 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/444603/88814

Comment: Thank's for the links. See my edited question. I tried different things, but the results are faulty in each case so far, unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my final solution:

[image: Model for creating service area dangles]

It is based on:

- [BERA's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/470872/52808) and [my answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/470889/52808) to **"Remove partly overlapping geometries from service area in QGIS"** (with "Snap geometries to layer" as crucial part of the fix)
- [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/469626/52808) to **"Finding number of lines touching intersection point (in polyline layer)"**

It seems to me that this is a "cleaner" solution than [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/470573/52808).

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

1. Explode lines on Service area layer, to create a line for each line segment.
2. Create a spatial index on the exploded lines.
3. Extract the vertices from the exploded lines.
4. Buffer the vertices with a small distance, I use 5 m.
5. Sum line lengths with the buffer output as Polygons and the indexed layer as Lines layer. Output will be a duplicate of the Buffer layer but with a Count attribute with the number of exploded lines intersecting each buffer.
6. Extract polygons by expression `"COUNT"=1`, to extract the end points which will only have one line to it.
7. Extract the vertices intersecting the extracted polygons:

[image]

My line network have some duplicate lines so all end points arent found. Maybe your line layer is better..:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @BERA. The problem is, that the resulting service area always includes duplicate edges (at least in my case) when exploded to single lines. So I had to extend your solution, as you can see in my new answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/470573/52808

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly? I tested different versions to drop duplicate geometries from the service area - without success.

Comment: OK. But the problem is that after your model, there are already many points missing (like in your screenshots) and I don't see how dropping duplicates might help here.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the problem that service areas (almost) always contain duplicate line segments, it had to be solved like this as an extended version of [BERA's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/470555/52808):

---

1. **"Explode lines"** of service area
2. **"Extract vertices"** of the exploded lines
3. Create a minimal **"Buffer"** for the extracted vertices
4. **"Sum line lengths"** of minimal "Buffer" and result from "Explode lines"
5. **"Join attributes by location"** (intersect) of "Extract vertices" and "Sum line lengths" results
6. **"Extract by expression"** (`count=1`) from result of "Join attributes by location"
7. **"Extract by expression"** (`count=2`) from result of "Join attributes by location"

---

8. **"Extract specific vertices"** from original network layer (`0,-1` for start point end end point of each line segment)
9. Add a minimal **"Buffer"** to the extracted network vertices
10. Perform an **"Intersection"** of the "Extract by expression" `count=2` result from above

---

11. **"Merge vector layers"** of the intersection result and the result of "Extract by expression" `count=1` result from above.

[image: Screenshot of the graphical model]

[image: Screenshot of final result]

This is due to the fact that because of overlapping line segments in the calculated service area, all vertices that are corresponding end points *and* end points in the original network have a count of 2, whereas all service area vertices that have no counterparts in the original network because they area located between its vertices have a count of 1. Thus, the vertices with a count of 2 only have to be kept if they correspond to a start point or an end point of the original network. See the following screenshot (the green count=2 vertices have to be removed).

[image: Screenshot showing count=1 and count=2 for all respective vertices]

I can hardly imagine that this is the most performant way to extract all dangles of a service area in QGIS, but so far (and based on the suggestions of others) this is the only working solution that I have found (at least for my specific use case).

**Please note:** Have a look at

- [Remove partly overlapping geometries from service area in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/470597/52808) and
- [Calculate network length covered by service area in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/470718/52808)

as I reason why I'm not satisfied with my own answer and thus can't accept it at the moment.

Comment: Maybe I should look for alternatives like `pgr_drivingDistance()` in `pgRouting` (e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/339553/52808) if better service area outputs are being created (without duplicates). I will iterate over lots of service areas in my productive workflow and with a complex model for "simple" steps like this I have serious performance problems.